# Java Thread Join method

Tags: java

How Join method work in Thread. If write join method in run method then its going to deadloack. Just need to information why its happening.

Code Snipet:

```
public class ThreadSchuduling extends Thread{
    static ThreadSchuduling threadObj3;
    public ThreadSchuduling(){
        System.out.println("Default Constructor");
    }
    public ThreadSchuduling(String name){
        System.out.println("Parameter Constructor");
    }
    public void run(){
        try{
            threadObj3.join();
        }catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println("Error in RUN "+e);
        }
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName());
        for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
            System.out.println("Value is = "+i);
        }

    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ThreadSchuduling threadObj1 = new ThreadSchuduling("Thread1");
        ThreadSchuduling threadObj2 = new ThreadSchuduling("Thread2");
        threadObj3 = new ThreadSchuduling("Thread3");
        ThreadSchuduling threadObj4 = new ThreadSchuduling("Thread4");

            threadObj1.start();
            threadObj2.start();
            threadObj3.start();
            System.out.println("Thread 3 is started");
            threadObj4.start();
            try{
            threadObj3.join();

        }catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println("Errpr "+e);
        }
        System.out.println("Main Method completed");
    }

}
```

I just want to complete the thread3 before the thread1 and thread2

Comment: first of all you have any idea how join method is work?

Answer (score 1):

You haven't explained what `threadObj3` is... is that a reference to the same thread? If so, it's understandable that it will deadlock - it's waiting until it's finished, which it won't do because it's waiting!

What are you actually trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

OMG,threadObj3 is always waiting by itself,if you want to complete thread3 before thread1 and thread2, you can set the priority,or it's hard to make sure thread3's execution before other thread.

Comment: Priority is more of a suggestion than a guarantee.